# Graph Database in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Are there any graph database in ruby . i have heard of neo4j in Jruby , Are there any pure implementation of graph database in ruby ?

Answer (score 5):

I have been researching this myself.  There are a number of interesting graph databases; however, Neo4j and OrientDB are the only ones for which I found any sort of Ruby API.

While not a true Graph Database, FlockDB uses a MySQL backend to mimic graph database constructs.

InfoGrid and HyperGraphDB looked interesting, but sadly, no Ruby API.

Answer (score 0):

I really like OrientDB and you can use it through REST although it would be somewhat minimal.